# How to place 1-10 images in a div with a given width without empty spaces?

Tags: html, css, django-templates

I'm trying to create a news feed. According to the idea, the user can attach up to 10 images to the post. Depending on the number of images, I want to arrange them in several rows with the entire block filled in.

#### Here are examples of the structure of images of one post.

[image]

#### The placement rules are as follows:

1. The pictures are arranged in several lines. The number of lines and the number of images per line depends on the template above.
2. Images fill the maximum width of the block. Their height changes so as to maintain the proportions and should be the same for all images in a row.
3. Adding small equal spaces between the pictures is welcome.
4. Since the height of the rows can change, the height of the parent block is not limited.
5. I use dynamic addition of post images to the template. Setting the dimensions of each element is a bad decision.
6. I would like to do without js.

#### Updated:

Now I do this: I form rows of images on the side of the data model and return row objects to the template. This seems to me a bad solution, since the display should not be set in the backend part of the site. I use the following code:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions

from userprofile.models import Profile


class Feed(models.Model):
    
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('published')
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pub_date) + ' ' + self.text
    
    @property
    def image_rows(self):
        
        if self.images.count() == 0:
            return None
        
        image_rows_grouping_template = [
            [1], [2], [1, 2], [2, 2], 
            [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4],
            [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 4]
        ]
        image_rows_template = image_rows_grouping_template[self.images.count()-2]
        
        rows = [ {'images': []} for i in range(len(image_rows_template))]
        
        # Images grouping in rows
        for image in self.images.all():
            for i, row in enumerate(image_rows_template):
                if row > 0:
                    rows[i]['images'].append(image)
                    image_rows_template[i] -= 1
                    break
        
        # Calculating ratio between row width & height
        for row in rows:
            
            ratio = 0
            for image in row['images']:
                
                width, height = get_image_dimensions(image.image.file)
                ratio += width / height
                
            row['ratio'] = ratio
        
        return rows
                    
    
class FeedImage(models.Model):
    
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='feeds-images')
    feed = models.ForeignKey(Feed, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
```

The context is assembled as follows:

```py
#views.py
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

from feeds.models import Feed


class FeedsListView(ListView):

    model = Feed
    paginate_by = 100
    
    template_name = 'home/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'feeds'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        
        return context
```

If dividing images into terms is a good solution, please provide an additional example of such string formation.

The last thing I tried was to place pictures using `flex-wrap: wrap`. I have very poor layout skills, so I didn't know that the pictures would be inserted with the original dimensions.
Now this part of the template looks like this:

```html
<div class="feed-images">
  {% for row in feed.image_rows %}
    <div class="feed-image-row" style="aspect-ratio: {{ row.ratio }};">
      {% for image in row.images %}
        <img src="{{ image.image.url }}"/>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

```css
.feed-images{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.feed-image-row{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.feed-image-row > img{
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

#### Summary

Now it works correctly, but I would like to add the distance between the pictures and the rows of pictures, and then the ratio calculation will be incorrect. I would like to abandon the calculation of the ratio in the model, and make a layout of images with a dynamic equal width in a row. If it is possible - to abandon the distribution of images by lines in the part of the model.

I will be grateful for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for creating an auto adjustable Gallery.

.css file:

```
.pics>img {
    width: 100%;
}

.gallery {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-width: 33%;
    -moz-column-width: 33%;
    column-width: 33%;
    column-gap: 0px;
}

.gallery .pics {
    -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease;
    transition: all 350ms ease;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.gallery .pics :hover {
    filter: opacity(.8);
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .gallery {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .gallery {
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
        -webkit-column-width: 100%;
        -moz-column-width: 100%;
        column-width: 100%;
    }
}

/* model */

.model {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: black;
    transition: opacity .4s ease, visibility .4s ease, transform .5s ease-in-out;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
}

.model .open {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.model>img {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
    line-height: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px 0 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is the html code:

```
<div className="gallery">
                <div className="pics" >
                    {data.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <>
                                <img data-tip data-for='img-details' src={item.imgsrc} />
                                <ReactTooltip id="img-details" type="warning" effect="float" place="bottom" />
                            </>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
```

If it brings any issue feel free to drop a comment or contact me on linkedin/in/haadbaig
I hope it solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I see that you use React elements - I do not know it and do not use it, but I will try to rework the code for my case and tell you about the results. If I have to connect the react, I will have to change the question tags))

Comment: No problem, I shared the raw code, you can rework it as simple html+css it will work. Do let me know the result.